# Resize Spinner width to selected item

Tags: android, spinner, android-appcompat

I'm using an AppCompatSpinner control that has both long and short items. When a short item is selected, the spinner is too wide, its icon appears too far away from the text because the text is so short. Is there a way to make the spinner smaller if the item is small?

Comment: did you tried using `spinner.setDropDownWidth(width); ` ?

Comment: I need `width` to be dynamic though

Answer (score 0):

This is quite hacky tho.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        String text = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.measureText(text);
        textPaint.setTextSize(45);
        textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        int width = bounds.width();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = spinner.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width + 290;
        spinner.setLayoutParams(params);
      }
      @Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
      }
    });
```

Hope it helps :)